# Generating an array with sub-arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I realize this is a somewhat off manner of operations, but for the sake of possibility, I'm wondering if anyone can help?

Here array2 is holding the end state I would like array1 to hold (only I want to do it with the for loop. It's fine that each sub_array's have to be initialized as their own variables, I'm just trying to get the array1 to hold N number of sub_arrays via the loop.

Here is the example I've tried, but trying to "compile" it via a string doesn't allow the sub_arrays to be called in a useable manner.

```
var numberOfSubArrays = 3
var sub_array1 = []
var sub_array2 = []
var sub_array3 = []

var array1 = []
var array2 = [sub_array1,sub_array2,sub_array3]

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSubArrays; i++) {
    array1[i] = "sub_array" + i
}
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `array1[i] = array2[i]`? Or perhaps some kind of concat?

Comment: Or `for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSubArrays; i++) {
    eval("array1[" + i  +"] = sub_array" + i);
}`

Comment: @mplungjan `array2` is an array holding references of other arrays. If it was an object with keys `sub_array1....n` then we could do just like you advised. Am i right?

Comment: Early morning here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var numberOfSubArrays = 3
var sub_array1 = [1]
var sub_array2 = [2]
var sub_array3 = [3]

var array1 = []
// we don't need array2 at all
//var array2 = [sub_array1,sub_array2,sub_array3]

// you need to count from 1..n, as you named your sub_arrays like that
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSubArrays; i++) {
    // you can use eval, but be careful, eval is evil!
    array1[i-1] = eval("sub_array" + i)
}
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Yes! I just didn't know eval was a thing. Many thanks

Comment: Right, but I think the intention was not to have the array2 in the code :)

Comment: I think array2 was just to show us what they want in array1 -- as in references to the arrays, not just their names as strings.

Comment: BTW, see my answer for an eval-free and BPA-free alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` is yucky.  This will work in browsers:

```
var numberOfSubArrays = 3
var sub_array1 = []
var sub_array2 = []
var sub_array3 = []

var array1 = []
var array2 = [sub_array1,sub_array2,sub_array3]

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSubArrays; i++) {
    array1[i] = window["sub_array" + i + 1];
}
```

In browsers, "global" vars are really objects in "window".
Note: this will not work in tools like jsfiddle, because they put your code inside a function (that you don't see).